# React componentDidMount vs getInitialState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some questions about react usage and patterns.

Should I use

```
componentDidMount
```

or

```
getInitialState
```

in loading data asynchronously?  What is the difference between the two?

I am using Backbone for my frontend data structures

```
this.props.data = new BrandModel({ _id: this.props.params.brandId });
var that = this;
this.props.data.fetch({
  success: function () {
    that.setState({ brand: that.props.brand });
  }
});
return null;
```

**Update:** thanks for the responses

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139366/why-do-the-react-docs-recommend-doing-ajax-in-componentdidmount-not-componentwi?rq=1) is suggesting to not us **componentWillMount**, but I understand that its more expressive to use **componentDidMount** in this case as **getInitialState** seems to be meant to be used synchronously

**Update 2:**

I've had to revert to using getInitialState as componentDidMount fires after render and I need this.props.data to be pointing to an object

Answer (score 9):

`componentDidMount` would be called after component was mounted into browser DOM (it would be called after first render and it would not be called if you are rendering server-side(to string)

`getInitialState` would be called when component is created, if you are using es6 class syntax you can place that logic in you component constructor directly assigning to `this.state`

There is also `componentWillMount` it would be called before first render for both server and client - it is more suitable in your case.

Answer (score 3):

Componentndid mount is fired after the render and we load the Ajax inside that.While during the actual render we check if the object has data, else send empty div

```
componentDidMount: function () {
            console.log("========> FIring");
            $.get("http://api.", function(response) {
                if (this.isMounted()) {
                    this.setState({
                    Data: response
                });
                }
            }.bind(this));
        },
        render: function() {
            var data = this.state.Data;
            if (this.state.promoData) {
             return (<div>{data}</div>
            );
            } else {
              return (<div className="divLoading">Loading...</div>);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this Backbone usage but if you load data in `componentDidMount` that's fine as essentially that code will start executing after the component is initially rendered -- after the data is fetched and the state is set again, the component will re-render showing that correct data at that point.  This kind of like lazy loading to me.

I'm not sure if `getInitialState` is blocking, but if it is, then the component will not render until the state is loaded.  But I think it isn't, so the data would probably not be fetched by the time the component is rendered.

`componentWillMount` may be what you want, but review the [React lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) for what you think makes the most sense.

Comment: `getInitialState` is not blocking — no React function is, unless one does something like `while (true) { console.log('a-long-loop'); }`