# React render nested component

Tags: reactjs

In the `return` method of my react component I want to have check to async function and return only if satisfied. This is my code:

```
render() {
      var data = new MyClass()
      data.helper(function(response){
         if(response.status === "authorised"){
           return (
              <div>
               <List videos={videos}/>
             </div>
            )

          }else{
            return (
              <div>
               <p>Please wait</p>
             </div>
            )
          }
       })


    }
```

But this way it is giving me error saying:

> A valid react component must be returned. You are returning either array or list or undefined

I want to show the data only after my logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest moving the AJAX call to the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method so the request fires when the DOM node is mounted, and then conditionally setting an `authorised` property on the state, contingent on a successful response. Then use this state property to conditionally render your different UI states in the `render` method:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { authorised: false };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var data = new MyClass();
    data.helper((response) => {
      if (response.status === "authorised") {
        this.setState({ authorised: true })
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.authorised) {
      return (
        <div>
          <List videos={videos}/>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Please wait</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The data.helper argument needs to be an arrow function (or a function with a bound `this`) in order to use `this.setState()`.

Comment: what if I use `componentWillMount` instead `componentDidMount`. I want to check before render

Comment: I've tried that approach and others' have documented it [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139366/why-do-the-react-docs-recommend-doing-ajax-in-componentdidmount-not-componentwi). The problem with performing AJAX in `componentWillMount` is that there's no guarantee that the asynchronous call complete by the time the method returns and the node is mounting. Depending on how you've organized your state this could cause your component to attempt to render using unset state (your authorised property might be still be false in this case).

Comment: One thing you could do is instead of returning `<p>Please wait</p>`, return `null` instead and nothing will render until the auth call is successfully completed.