# Why ajax request should be done in componentDidMount in React components?

Tags: reactjs

React documentation states that ajax request should be initiated from  `componentDidMount` lifecycle event (see  [react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount)) .

Why this event?

In most cases, when loading data using ajax, I want to display some kind of loading bar, e.g.:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.setState({isLoading: true});
   fetch(...)
      .then(...)
      .then(() => this.setState({isLoading: false})  
}
```

but this fires `render` method 3 times (initial render immediatelly followed by setting `isLoading = true` and then by `isLoading = false`

What's wrong about sending ajax request from `componentWillMount` event?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do the React docs recommend doing AJAX in componentDidMount, not componentWillMount?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139366/why-do-the-react-docs-recommend-doing-ajax-in-componentdidmount-not-componentwi)

Comment: @mattias: Thanks, I find the answer in the linked question very useful and I recommend anybody interested in this question to have a look at it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `isLoading: true` could be part of the initial state, no need to set it after component did mount => only 2 renderings, not 3.

According to https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/210, the consequence of calling `render` only once from `componentWillMount` means that if `setState` will be asynchronously called after `render`, it won't have any effect (if I understand the comments correctly).

Not sure if there is a chance that the callback with `setState` can execute before `render` and thus no loading screen will be visible, only the results, thus sometimes it would "work" (most likely in DEV) but in reality it would be a race condition very hard to debug...

See also: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

Comment: the issue has been fixed, so setState called from componentWillMount will take effect before render. in the react docs there is still no explanation why  ajax calls should be done in componentDidMount

Comment: well, you are not calling `setState` from componentWillMount nor componentDidMount directly, but from a new async stack. I have no idea how exactly react is implemented to keep reference to `this` with live event listeners from various methods. if using undocumented features is not scary enough for you and want a bit of excitement that it might work and maybe even in future versions, then feel free, I don't know whether it will break or not

Answer (score 0):

Point is let your react component render with the initial state so that you will see the loading bar (loading: true).

You can move line: this.setState({isLoading: true}) in componentWillMount() .
Because setting state in componentWillMount wont trigger a rerender of your component .Your render method will get the updated component.