# Can I put ajax in React component constructor?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';

class AjaxInConstructor extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { name: '', age: '' };
    this.loadData().then((data) => {
      this.setState(data);
    });
  }
  // simulate the AJAX (network I/O)
  public loadData() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({
          name: 'slideshowp2',
          age: 123,
        });
      }, 2000);
    });
  }

  public render() {
    const { name, age } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Can I init component state async?</p>
        <p>name: {name}</p>
        <p>age: {age}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<AjaxInConstructor />, document.body);
```

Above is my demo code. I know people always put ajax in `componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount` lifecycle.

But this case also works.

In chrome `console`, `React` throw no error and waring. So, My Question is usage like this is completely correct ? Is there have some error?

Comment: Theres no AJAX here and what you have done seems fine

Comment: If your component is passed to another component but only displayed if a specific condition is met, the AJAX call will always be triggered even if the component is not mounted / displayed so `componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount` are better suited.

Comment: Also it is not convenient way, but answer to your question, is yes, you can.

Comment: @Martin yes, I just simulate async process.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can make an AJAX call wherever you want. There is nothing "wrong" in making an AJAX call in the constructor, but there is a catch. You'll want to make the AJAX call only after the component has been mounted or just before it is about to be mounted.

So before component is rendered, making an AJAX call in `componentDidMount()` or `componentWillMount()` is recommended. Just because React allows to do "things" does not mean you should! :)

**UPDATE**

I also realize that initially my answer wasn't rigorous. I have always followed what fellow programmer have followed, blindly.

After searching a bit I found these to be one step closer to the complete answer-
[Why ajax request should be done in componentDidMount in React components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38180704/why-ajax-request-should-be-done-in-componentdidmount-in-react-components)

Essence of those answer says that when you call `setState()` in `componentWillMount()`, the component will not re-render. Therefore one must use `componentDidMount()`. After further reading I learned that it was fixed in subsequent release by React team. You can now call `setState()` in `componentWillMount()`. I think that is the reason why everyone recommends making AJAX calls in `didMount`.

One of the comments also puts forth my thoughts very articulately-

> well, you are not calling setState from componentWillMount nor
>   componentDidMount directly, but from a new async stack. I have no idea
>   how exactly react is implemented to keep reference to this with live
>   event listeners from various methods. if using undocumented features
>   is not scary enough for you and want a bit of excitement that it might
>   work and maybe even in future versions, then feel free, I don't know
>   whether it will break or not

Comment: Yes. When I am learning `React`, I find many **not sure** questions. There always have no absolute correct anwsers. I think this is not rigorous!

Comment: OK, Thank You! It seems there is no any other people want to awnser this question.

Comment: > _when you call `setState()` in `componentWillMount()`, the component will not re-render._
Don't confuse `setState()` and `render()`. You don't need **re-render**  component in order to update its state. But what you need is exactly 1) update component's state 2) re-render component with **updated** state.
So calling `setState()` in `componentWillMount()` is even more perfect approach than to call it in `componentDidMount()`.

Comment: `componentWillMount()` method can be executed multiple times in React 16+. Also, AJAX calls are asynchronous so the state is very likely to get set after the component has been mounted. Constructors and `componentDidMount()` method are only executed once.

Comment: @Mihir But what if I am not calling setState in `constructor`? My requirement is to fetch some data that needs to be displayed on initial page load, and I don't want to render incomplete UI so I show a spinner until data loads. To minimize loading time, I have put the ajax call in `constructor` instead of `componentDidMount`. And I only render the UI when ajax resolves.