# React router params change trigger firebase query

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-router

I currently have a router set up in my React app that has a link with query params:

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/details/:id" component={Details} />
</Router>
```

What I want to do is query my firebase database when the user navigates to the details page (i.e `/details/123`). This code in the `Details` component will be:

```
const id = this.props.params.id;
const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
rootRef.orderByChild("id").equalTo(id).on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
  this.setState({
    user: snapshot.value()
  });
});
```

Where would I put the code that queries the firebase database? I would have thought it should not go in the render method as it does not belong there as I am setting the state - is this correct?. I have tried using the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle function but that does not seem to get called - am I misunderstanding the lifecycles and how react-router works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`render` is not the right place to put it, because there's a very strong convention that `render` should be pure (i.e., it shouldn't modify a component's state).

`componentWillReceiveProps` isn't right, either, because `componentWillReceiveProps` [is not called when a component first mounts](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/componentWillReceiveProps-not-triggered-after-mounting.html).

The typical place to load necessary state is from [componentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount). (Using componentWillMount could technically work, too, but if you're doing server-side rendering, then componentWillMount will execute on the server, and dispatching AJAX or database requests from the server instead of the client can cause issues. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27139507/25507).)

To be *really* robust, you'd also want to handle the case where the component is unmounted before your asynchronous database query finishes, because calling `setState` on an unmounted component will trigger a warning. [The React blog](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html) has some suggested techniques for handling that.

Since you're using react-router, another option is to issue your database query from [the route's onEnter event](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback), so that the route doesn't even transition until the database query has finished. I don't have experience with this approach.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thanks.