# Render the data using API in react.js?

Tags: api, reactjs

I have an API where `title, description, old price` and `new price` should be rendered, but I have no idea how to do it right way.

Here content component with my API

```
export class Content extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={};
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        var url="95.85.23.63:8000/frontend/web/api/v1/user/get-popular";
        Request.get(url).then((reponse)=>{
            this.setState({
                infos:response.body.Search,
                total:response.body.totalResults
            });
        });
    }

    render(){
        var infos=_.map(this.state.infos, (info)=>{
            return <li>{info.title}</li>;
        });

        return(
        <div>
        <ul> {infos}</ul>

        </div>
        )
    }

}
```

I think I'm retrieving the data in a wrong way. Could you please help me?

Comment: You should create the actions, Then either you can use react-thunk or react-saga to retrieve the data from the api's. when the component is mounted, means componentDidMount(){ this.props.dispatch(search())}

Answer (score 0):

You're doing and `async` call. So, you need to handle the empty state in render. See the following code

**[EDIT]**

As mentioned in the comment, it is recommended to to the request in `componentDidMount()`

```
export class Content extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
           infos: [],
           total: 0,
        };
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        var url="95.85.23.63:8000/frontend/web/api/v1/user/get-popular";
        Request.get(url).then((reponse)=>{
            this.setState({
                infos:response.body.Search,
                total:response.body.totalResults
            });
        });
    }

    render(){
        if(this.state.infos.length === 0)
          return false //return false when nothing is in the state
        var infos=_.map(this.state.infos, (info)=>{
            return <li>{info.title}</li>;
        });

        return(
        <div>
        <ul> {infos}</ul>

        </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: I think we are not supposed to do ajax request in componentwillMount, it may trigger infinite loop and might block the component from mounting. We should write it in componentdidMount

Comment: That's not true. You shouldn't setState on `componentDidUpdate`. This will cause infinite loop. Hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139366/why-do-the-react-docs-recommend-doing-ajax-in-componentdidmount-not-componentwi

Comment: Thanks for the tip!