# Dynamically add button in React to do a update/delete request

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I have a React frontend that posts to my node api, a simple todo kind of deal. I want to list all of the movies/todos and I have that working just fine. However, when I do a forEach on all of the returned movies to dynamically add a table row and its table data, I am including a button to delete the movie from the list. Everything shows up as expected, but the delete button does nothing. It does not look right but I am out of ideas.

Here is the handleGetMovies function which is where the problem lives:

```
        handleGetMovies() {
        $.get( "http://localhost:8080/api/movies", function( movies ) {
            movies.forEach(function( movie ) {
                $('#movieList').append('<tr><td>' + movie.title + '</td><td>' + movie.genre + '</td><td>' + movie.year + 
                '</td><td>' + movie.actors + '</td><td>' + movie.rating + '</td><td><button id=' + movie._id + 
                'onClick="{this.handleDelete.bind(this,id)}"' +'>Delete Title</button></td></tr>');
            })
        });
    }
```

Here it is altogether:

```
    class Hello extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        return console.log('In componentWillMount')
    }
    handleSubmit() {
        let movie = {
            title: this.title.value,
            genre: this.genre.value,
            year: this.year.value,
            actors: this.actors.value.split(','),
            rating: this.rating.value
        }
        console.log(movie);

        $.post( "http://localhost:8080/api/movies", movie );
    }

    handleDelete() {
        console.log('>>>>> deleteID', deleteId)
        let deleteId = this.deleteMovie.value;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/movies/' + deleteTitle,
            type: 'DELETE',
            success: function(result) {
            }
        });
    }

    handleGetMovies() {
        $.get( "http://localhost:8080/api/movies", function( movies ) {
            movies.forEach(function( movie ) {
                $('#movieList').append('<tr><td>' + movie.title + '</td><td>' + movie.genre + '</td><td>' + movie.year + 
                '</td><td>' + movie.actors + '</td><td>' + movie.rating + '</td><td><button id=' + movie._id + 
                'onClick="{this.handleDelete.bind(this,id)}"' +'>Delete Title</button></td></tr>');
            })
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (   
            <div>     
                <input placeholder="Title" id="title" type="text" ref={(input) => { this.title = input; }}/>  
                <input placeholder="Genre" id="genre" type="text" ref={(input) => { this.genre = input; }}/> 
                <input placeholder="Year" id="year" type="text" ref={(input) => { this.year = input; }}/> 
                <input placeholder="Rober De Niro, Joe Pesci" id="actors" type="text" ref={(input) => { this.actors = input; }}/> 
                <input placeholder="Rating" id="rating" type="text" ref={(input) => { this.rating = input; }}/> 
                <button onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>Add</button><br></br>
                <button onClick={this.handleGetMovies.bind(this)}>Show All Movies</button>

                <table id ="movieList" className="table table-striped">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Genre</th>
                        <th>Year</th>
                        <th>Actors</th>
                        <th>Rating</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>  
        )
    }
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello name="World" />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: I think you should reference your `$('#movieList')` as `this.movieList.append...`, and in your render method, you update your table as `<table id='movieList' ref={(list) => { this.movieList = list;} ...` and, in your `movies.forEach` function, pass 'this' at final, such as `movies.forEach(function(movie) { ... }, this)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this.handleDeleteMovie` would work inside of the render function JSX, but (I believe) your issue is that JSX doesn't work in the jquery methods, and you are currently trying to use a jsx-specific event handler inside jquery. (someone please edit this if I'm wrong)

I would recommend setting the movies from the get request in state:

at the top:

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {}
}
```

then in <s>`handleGetMovies()`</s> change to: `componentDidMount`
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139366/why-do-the-react-docs-recommend-doing-ajax-in-componentdidmount-not-componentwi) for more info about why to perform your AJAX inside `componentDidMount`

```
$.get( "http://localhost:8080/api/movies", ( movies )=>{
//be sure to use the arrow function, so that the this binding will carry over
    this.setState({movies: movies})
}
```

Finally, in your render function, you can include:

```
<div>
/*other code and stuff*/
{this.state.movies.map((movie)=>{
    <div>
        /*elements for each movie, and your handledelete would work here*/
    </div>
    }
}
</div>
```

Then, to prevent errors from trying to map an array that doesn't exist yet, you have two options: 
1) Set the initial state in `constructor` to be `this.state = { movies: [] }`
**OR** (possibly the better way)
2) change your jsx to `{ this.state.movies && /*do your map here*/ }`, which says if `this.state.movies` is truthy, then execute the following code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, when I do that, the state always remains as an empty object, as when it is initialized in the constructor. At first I thought that would be resolved by calling the done method on the ajax call, but it did not. Any ideas on that? Initializing the state via the ajax call seems simple but it is not working.

Comment: Ah, yes -- if you make the get request inside of a `componentDidMount` method then the get request will be made after the state is already initialized. So you would need to change `handleGetMovies` to `componentDidMount`. I just edited my answer to reflect that, sorry about that!

Comment: I just added a bit more detail and corrections to my answer, so it should be more helpful now

Comment: Thanks, what I did was to add the async: false to the ajax get request, and that solved the issue

Comment: Ah, that will work too.. but then it just becomes a "jax" request ;) The accepted practice seems to be putting the ajax request in componentDidMount, but here's an interesting discussion on componentWillMount, and constructor:https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7671