# Why is my render function running before my componentWillMount

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Whenever I try to fetch my results from componentWillMount the application hits render() first it comes out and then it hits componentWillMount fetches my results, sets the state and then hits render again.

```
componentWillMount= () => {
    let team = gh.getRepo('Microsoft', 'vscode');
    team.getContributors(function(err, members){
    }).then(response => {
      this.setState({
         data: response.data
      });
   });
}


render() {
    var ghList = this.state.data;
    const names = ghList.map(name => { //when it runs the first time this map in invalid since ghList is null from my this.setState= {data:null}
})
return (
      <div className="flip-container" onClick={this.onTileClick}>
        <div className="flipper">
          <div className="front">
              <img className="circle" src={this.state.avatar_url} alt={this.state.login}/>
          </div>
        <div className="back">
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
)
```

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle or something we an try?

Comment: It's recomended that AJAX calls are made from componentDidMount. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139366/why-do-the-react-docs-recommend-doing-ajax-in-componentdidmount-not-componentwi

Comment: Made the change thanks I'll add this to my dev notes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, it's the expected behavior. What is happening:

1. **componentWillMount():** triggers an async request (`getContributors`).
2. **render()** first time, with `this.state.data` = `undefined`.
3. callback from `getContributors` is called (the response has come), and, then, `setState` is invoked: setState schedules a new rendering.
4. **render()** second time, with populated `this.state.data`

**You'll have to handle your initial state rendering** (how your component will render before the ajax returns: maybe some loading spinner..). So, in the render method, you can check if `this.state.data` is `null`/`undefined` and bypass your logic. Or, in constructor, set your data to an empty array:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    data: []
  }
}
```

This way, at least `ghList.map` will not thrown an error.