# ReactJS beginner state updated but rendering in child not

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Bear with me beginner at ReactJS so I am testing stuff out.

I created a static page as a component and in that component I load another custom component.

The data is coming from an ajax call and I update the state but it doesn't update the child component's view.

The static page

```
// Test.JS
import React from 'react';
import Layout from '../../components/Layout';
import Article from '../../components/Article';
import s from './styles.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class Test extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        article: null
    };

}

componentWillMount(){
    axios.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/koistya/a32919e847531320675764e7308b796a/raw/articles.json")
        .then(function(result) {
            var theArticle = result.data.filter((article) => article.title.split(' ').join('') === this.props.route.params.title.split(' ').join(''));
            this.setState({
                article: theArticle[0]
            })
        }.bind(this));
 }

render() {
    return (
        <Layout className={s.content}>
            <Article {...this.state.article} />
        </Layout>
    );
}

}

export default Test;
```

As you can see i update the state with an ajax call but the child is not updated. the console log in Article is showing a null object because first time it renders there is nothing inside. But after updating the state I expect it should pass it through to the childeren.

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from '../Link';

class Article extends React.Component{

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props);
        window.componentHandler.upgradeElement(this.root);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.componentHandler.downgradeElements(this.root);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp" ref={node => (this.root = node)}>
                <div className="mdl-card__title">
                    <h2 className="mdl-card__title-text">{this.props.author}</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                </div>
                <div className="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
                </div>
                <div className="mdl-card__menu">
                    <button className="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                        <i className="material-icons">{this.props.title}</i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
    );
    }

}

export default Article;
```

So I have the following questions:

1) First of all am I going the right direction is this how it should be done ?
2) Is a constructer not better than willmount event ? 
2) Why is it now not updating the child view ?
3) Should I use a prop or state in this case (in Test.js) (still not sure after reading allot about it)

Comment: Unrelated, but you probably want `componentDidMount`, and `theArticle` isn't a great name for an array. Have you debugged to know that you're actually getting the data you want?

Comment: @DaveNewton WillMount is a step before Didmount right ? I don't need to wait till it mounts to get data...yeah the variableName its just a test not a real project :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27139366/438992

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks :) guess not same as application life cycles

Comment: So you're saying that you get the expected data for `state.article` from `Test/render()` but not in `Article/render()`? That would be very surprising. Does it work if you remove the `componentHandler` stuff?

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to componentDidMount and now it updates the view.

I have no idea why it didnt work before!