# Can I call APIs in componentWillMount in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on react for last 1 year. The convention which we follow is make an API call in `componentDidMount`, fetch the data and setState after the data has come. This will ensure that the component has mounted and setting state will cause a re-render the component but I want to know why we can't setState in `componentWillMount` or `constructor`

The official documentation says that :

> componentWillMount() is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It
>   is called before render(), therefore setting state in this method will
>   not trigger a re-rendering. Avoid introducing any side-effects or
>   subscriptions in this method.

it says `setting state in this method will not trigger a re-rendering`, which I don't want while making an API call. If I'm able to get the data and able to set in the state (assuming API calls are really fast) in `componentWillMount` or in `constructor` and data is present in the first render, why would I want a re-render at all?

and if the API call is slow, then `setState` will be async and `componentWillMount` has already returned then I'll be able to setState and a re-render should occur.

As a whole, I'm pretty much confused why we shouldn't make API calls in constructor or componentWillMount. Can somebody really help me understand how react works in such case?

Comment: Make API call in `componentWillMount` if you need that isn't bad idea, but it isn't possible to have response from API and set appropriate state before first render will be called.

Comment: @elmeister - if your API goes through a cacheing layer, you may be able to get a cached result to your query synchronously.

Comment: Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27139366/465053).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**1. `componentWillMount` and re-rendering**

Compare this two `componentWillMount` methods.
One causes additional re-render, one does not

```
componentWillMount () {
  // This will not cause additional re-render
  this.setState({ name: 'Andrej '});
}

componentWillMount () {
  fetch('http://whatever/profile').then(() => {
    // This in the other hand will cause additional rerender,
    // since fetch is async and state is set after request completes.
    this.setState({ name: 'Andrej '});
  })
}
```

.
.
.
**2. Where to invoke API calls?**

```
componentWillMount () {
  // Is triggered on server and on client as well.
  // Server won't wait for completion though, nor will be able to trigger re-render
  // for client.
  fetch('...')
}

componentDidMount () {
  // Is triggered on client, but never on server.
  // This is a good place to invoke API calls.
  fetch('...')
}
```

If you are rendering on server and your component does need data for rendering, you should fetch (and wait for completion) outside of component and pass data thru props and render component to string afterwards.

Answer (score 6):

**[ComponentWillMount](https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/birth/premounting_with_componentwillmount.html)**

> Now that the **props and state are set**, we finally enter the realm of Life Cycle methods

That means React expects `state` to be available as `render` function will be called next and code can break if any mentioned state variable is missing which may occur in case of `ajax`.

---

**[Constructor](https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/birth/initialization_and_construction.html)**

> This is the place where you define.

So Calling an ajax will not update the values of any state as ajax is async and constructor will not wait for response. Ideally, you should use constructor to set *default/initial* values.

---

Ideally these functions should be pure function, only depending on parameters. Bringing `ajax` brings side effect to function.

Yes, functions depend on `state` and using `this.setState` can bring you such issues (*You have set value in state but value is missing in state in next called function*).

This makes code fragile. If your API is really fast, you can pass this value as an argument and in your component, check if this arg is available. If yes, initialise you state with it. If not, set it to default. Also, in success function of ajax, you can check for `ref` of this component. If it exist, component is rendered and you can call its `state` using `setState`  or any `setter`(*preferred*) function.

Also remember, when you say *API calls are really fast*, your server and processing may be at optimum speed, but you can never be sure with network.

Comment: Im not an expert, so there is a possibility, I might have made mistakes. Please comment along with your vote, if there are any inconsistencies.

Comment: but what if I have put some default states in constructor which does not break the render. Also the setState is called after the render has returned, as it will be treated as an event by React. How `componentWillMount` will cause difficulties?

Answer (score 0):

If you need just data only at first run and if you are ok with that. You can setState synchronously via calling a callback.

for eg:

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.setState({
                sessionId: sessionId,                
            }, () => {
                if (this.state.hasMoreItems = true) {
                    this.loadItems()   // do what you like here synchronously 
                }
            });
}
```