# I don't understand how components are mounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use pattern container/representational components.
I have `CardContainer` component which fetch data from a server and pass it to a `Card` component
Container component:

```
class CardContainer extends Component {
    state = {
        'card': null
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`${BASEURL}/api/cards/${this.props.params._id}/`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(card => this.setState({'card': card}))
   }

    render() {
        return <CardDetail card={this.state.card} />
   }
```

Representational component:

```
class CardDetail extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.card._id}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

In that case I have an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null

So render method of a child called before `componentDidMount` of a parrent.
But in the case when I pass stateless function component to a child all works fine:

```
const FunctionChild = props => <h1>{props._id}</h1>

class CardDetail extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <FunctionChild {...this.props.card} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I use console.log in components `render` and in a `componentDidMount` method to understand the method resolution:

1. Mount container
2. Mount child
3. Mount function child
4. DidMount container method

So `componentDidMount` still called last but all works fine. Please someone explain what am I missing.

Comment: No. Your `fetch` is an async task, so your response comes after lifecycle methods are executed. I wrote an answer on similar qyery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154544/can-i-call-apis-in-componentwillmount-in-react/43154733#43154733

Comment: @Rajesh I understand but why it works with `FunctionChild` child component in my example?

Comment: I'm not really sure. Have you tried logging `id` in both approaches?

Comment: @IvanSemochkin it works with stateless component because the component is a new one each time, fully described by props so it always has an _id

Comment: Yes I understand it now, thanks guys. Stateles components was recieved only an `_id` so the first time it just received empty object and after `fetch` is done it receive an `_id`. But if I'll don't use `{...props}` syntax and just pass the props directly. It will crush with same error because props will be `null` first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason is, initially you defined the card value as `null`, and accessing the value of id, that's why it is throwing the error :

> can not access property id of null

Because you are fetching the data from `api`, it is `asynchronous call` and will take time to `return` the data, until you didn't get the data, value of card will be `null`.

One way of fixing this is, initialise the card with `{}` instead of `null`, like this:

```
class CardContainer extends Component {
    state = {
        'card': {}  //change this
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`${BASEURL}/api/cards/${this.props.params._id}/`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(card => this.setState({'card': card}))
   }

    render() {
        return <CardDetail card={this.state.card} />
   }
```

Or put the check inside the child component before accessing the id value, like this:

```
class CardDetail extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.card && this.props.card._id}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you help me a lot!

Comment: glad, it helped you :)