# Calling action from constructor vs a life cycle method

Tags: reactjs, redux

Where's the best place to call an action that will make an API call to hydrate my state? Constructor or one of the life cycle methods e.g. ComponentWillMount?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It will be better to make the api calls from lifecycle method `componentDidMount`, react doc also suggested the same.

As per [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount):

**[componentDidMount:](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)**

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. **If you
>   need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to
>   instantiate the network request.** Setting state in this method will
>   trigger a re-rendering.

Comment: Thank you! The only thing that makes me pause is where it says "this method will trigger a re-rendering". I know we should follow the DOC but maybe ComponentWillMount may be another good place?

Comment: check this answer it explained why we should not make api call in componentWillMount: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154544/can-i-call-apis-in-componentwillmount-in-react/43154733

Comment: as per doc: "setting the state in componentWillMount will not trigger the re-rendering." we should not use this method for api calls.

Comment: I feel this has a good write-up regarding `componentDidMount` vs `componentWillMount`https://tylermcginnis.com/react-interview-questions/. The short version is, React will in the future will call `componentDidMount` many times during rerender, causing unwanted behavior. The other reason is that the call may resolve before the component is mounted, therefore trying to set setState before there even is a component. https://engineering.musefind.com/react-lifecycle-methods-how-and-when-to-use-them-2111a1b692b1 is also a good source regarding lifecycle methods.

Comment: Also, regarding the 'this function will trigger a re-rendering', it is because the component already exists by the time `componentDidMount` runs, therefore it needs to rerender when a new state is set with `this.setState`. As a little note, usually I have a `state.loaded` to denote when information that I need has loaded,

Comment: @SammyI. thanks for the details and attached links have a very nice explanation :)

Comment: The plan is to deprecate componentWillMount() in React 17. Yet another reason to use componentDidMount().