# Ensure loading data in parent component before it renders child component

Tags: reactjs, parameter-passing, parent-child, loading

I have parent component that is connected to `Redux's store`, because I call action in its `constructor` and load `translation` (translation is also saved in store). Then, I render child component and pass `translationn` as props to it. Sometimes it happens that `render` method renders Child component before data is fetched. Actually, I get error on this line (`props.translation is undefined, unexpected token in JSON.parse()....`):

```js
let translation = JSON.parse(this.props.translation);
```

How can I postpone render method until translation data is fetched? Here is parent component code:

```js
class ConnectedTranslationProvider extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        if(!props.translation){
        props.translationsActions.loadTranslation(this.props.language);
        }
    }

    render() {
        let translation = JSON.parse(this.props.translation);
        let language = this.props.language;

        return (
            <TranslationProvider translation={translation} language={language}>
                {this.props.children}
            </TranslationProvider>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        language: state.language, 
        translation: state.translation
    }
}


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        translationsActions: bindActionCreators(translationsActions, dispatch)
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ConnectedTranslationProvider);
```

Comment: Can you please check my answer? If you have any questions - feel free to ask.

Comment: I checked it of course, thank you very much. It was useful, but I did a little bit different thing. I set `translation` variable conditionally, if `props.translation` exists, set variable to it, otherwise set it to empty object.

Comment: Yeah! There are a few possible way for doing it. Maybe the safe one is to short-circuit the render.

Answer (score 0):

You can short-circuit your render method, if there is no `props.translation`:

```
render() {
    // You can show a message here or a Loading component
    if (!this.props.translation) return </div>

    let translation = JSON.parse(this.props.translation);
    let language = this.props.language;

    return (
        <TranslationProvider translation={translation} language={language}>
            {this.props.children}
        </TranslationProvider>
    );
}
```

Also [React suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44812019/4312466) to do external API calls in `componentDidMount`, instead of the constructor.