# Passing new state to child component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I connected Home **component props with action method** and dispatch the reducer successfuly. All seems to work fine, I can see Api data coming to reducer in console.

Problem is, react doesn't re-render **ProfileGroupsWidget**. this.props.user is always {} in this child component, I was expecting it to be {name: "John Doe"}

Here is **userReducer**, "GET_AUTH_USER_SUCCESS" comes from **getAuthenticatedUser**:

```
const initialState = {};

const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_AUTH_USER_SUCCESS':
            console.log('Output:', action.user); // {name: "John Doe"}
            state = action.user
            return state;
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export {userReducer}
```

Home is my **Home component**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ProfileGroupsWidget from './Widgets/ProfileGroupsWidget.js'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {userActions} from "../_actions/userActions";

class Home extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user: this.props.user
        }
        this.props.getAuthenticatedUser();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ProfileGroupsWidget user={this.state.user}></ProfileGroupsWidget>
        )
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return state
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return {
        getAuthenticatedUser : () => {dispatch(userActions.getAuthenticatedUser())}
    }
}

// Connect Home component props with store data:
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `this.props.user` will always be undefined because you are not setting the value for it in the reducer. We have to set the value in the following way:

**Edited Code:**

```
const initialState = {
 user: {}
};

const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_AUTH_USER_SUCCESS':
           return { ...state, user: action.user };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export { userReducer }
```

**Edited Code:**
In home component: (in mapStateToProps, I have maintained `userReducer` as identifier, please change it to whatever reducer name you have used in the rootReducer).

We can also remove the constructor code entirely if you like, and move the action dispatch to `componentWillMount()`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ProfileGroupsWidget from './Widgets/ProfileGroupsWidget.js'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { userActions } from "../_actions/userActions";

class Home extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          user: props.user
        }
        props.getAuthenticatedUser();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ProfileGroupsWidget user={this.props.user}></ProfileGroupsWidget>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   user: state.userReducer.user
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  getAuthenticatedUser: () => dispatch(userActions.getAuthenticatedUser())
});

// Connect Home component props with store data:
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Comment: Thank you...but than props.user is always {}. I tried calling within componentDidMount also.

Comment: In the constructor, props.user will always be empty, because in the initialState of your reducer, user is empty. Once you call `getAuthenticatedUser()` in constructor/componentWillMount(), the action will be dispatched and user will be set, and in the subsequent renders, you can see `console.log(this.props.user); // { name: "John Doe" }`

Comment: Thank you.I somehow solved the problem combining your answer with Tyro Hunter's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you passing props.user to your state? That should be unnecessary based on your current code. With that, it would be better to assign `this.props.user` directly to ProfileGroupsWidget. That is if your redux is working and connected properly to your component.

Another thing here ([Calling action from constructor vs a life cycle method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44811983/calling-action-from-constructor-vs-a-life-cycle-method)), it's better to call network requests or actions inside `componentDidMount` rather than in your constructor:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.getAuthenticatedUser();
}
```

If you have everything correct you should see multiple console.logs of `this.props.user` if you log it inside render():

```
render() {
  console.log(this.props.user);
  /*
    should be called at least twice,
    the last one containing the data {name: "John Doe"}
  */

  return (
    <ProfileGroupsWidget user={this.props.user}></ProfileGroupsWidget>
  )
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it works. Meanwhile, I also added a "loading" prop, which renders widget only after reducer sets the values.