# Where to put socket.io code in a component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to connect to the `coincap.io` public `socket.io` API. I have everything set up but don't know where in my component to put the `socket.io` code. Does it go in the `constructor` or `componentWillMount` or where? It's `socket.io` so it obviously always needs to be open so where in a component would that go? Here is the code I need to inject somewhere into my component:

```
this.socket = io.connect('http://socket.coincap.io');
this.socket.on('connect', function(tradeMsg) {
    console.log("It worked");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does it go in the constructor or componentWillMount?

Check these answers for details about this:

[Can I call APIs in componentWillMount in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154544/can-i-call-apis-in-componentwillmount-in-react)

[Why do the React docs recommend doing AJAX in componentDidMount, not componentWillMount?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139366/why-do-the-react-docs-recommend-doing-ajax-in-componentdidmount-not-componentwi)

> Where in my component to put the socket.io code?

Use componentDidMount lifecycle method for, it will triggered only once after the component has been mounted successfully, we should write all kind of network calls inside this.

As per **[DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)**:

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you
>   need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to
>   instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will
>   trigger a re-rendering.

Write it like this:

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.socket = io.connect('http://socket.coincap.io');
    this.socket.on('connect', function(tradeMsg) {
        console.log("It worked");
    });
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you. The problem is that it's socket.io not a normal api request so if it is only called 1 time in componentDidMount() then how can the connection still be open and listening?

Comment: What I did was create a separate file to connect and solicit the socket. I call the connect method from the login where I use the same authentication process as the regular express endpoints that is to say middleware. I have my JWT stored in two cookies which are sent with both my api and socket calls. The middleware on my server reconstructs the JWT and authenticates using it in both the case of express and socket.io. This allows you to call the aforementioned connect method in componentDidMount reconnecting if the socket is null, the cookies survive the refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `socket` code into 'componentDidMount`. refer [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.socket = io.connect('http://socket.coincap.io');
    this.socket.on('connect', function(tradeMsg) {
      console.log("It worked");
    });
}
```