# axios.get can't display data

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a problem with my axios. I want to read data from json and display itg in the form of table. This is my code

```
constructor(props){
        super(props)
        data: []
     }

componentWillMount(){
    axios.get('http://localhost:3030/Personel')
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.setState({
           datas: response.data
        })
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
   }

   render(){
    console.log("lagi ngerender nih")
       return(
        <div>
        <Table>
            <TableHeader >
            <TableRow>
                <TableHeaderColumn>
                    <div>
                   <IconPerson /> <p> Data Personil </p>
                   </div>
                </TableHeaderColumn>
            </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableHeaderColumn>#</TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn>Nama Personil</TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn>Posisi</TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn>Jenis Kelamin</TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn>TB/BB</TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn>No.Handphone</TableHeaderColumn>
                </TableRow>
            </TableHeader>
            <TableBody>
                {this.state.datas.map((data, i) => (
                    <TableRow key={i}>
                        <TableRowColumn>{data.id}</TableRowColumn>
                        <TableRowColumn>{data.fullName}</TableRowColumn>
                        <TableRowColumn>{data.posisi}</TableRowColumn>
                        <TableRowColumn>{data.isMale? "Laki-laki": "Perempuan"}</TableRowColumn>
                        <TableRowColumn>{data.height+ "cm / " + data.weight+ "kg"}</TableRowColumn>
                        <TableRowColumn>{data.phoneNo}</TableRowColumn>
                    </TableRow>
                ))}
            </TableBody>
        </Table>
        </div>
       )
   }
}
```

and i got this error:
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'datas' of null"
It's seems that render() is fired before axios. how can i fixed this problem? Thank's

Comment: You should be able to fire the call in componentDidMount instead or provide an initial value in constructor. You can also selectively render your table rows by doing something like `{this.state.datas.length > 0 && this.state.datas.map . . .}`

Comment: May I please have a look at you `constructor`?

Comment: I have edit my question with adding constructor in my code

Comment: Is that how you declared your `state`, by doing `data: []` or did you actually do `this.state = { data: [] }`?

Answer (score 0):

The error is not- "render() is fired before axios".
That is not possible as `componentWillMount` is fired before `render`.

Here, the response from the api call is getting set asynchronously. That means your axios call is made, but there's no waiting for the response and render is called after axios call. i.e.

```
componentWillMount -> axios -> render -> response from axios
```

You need to render data only after you have the response. Check this-

[Can I call APIs in componentWillMount in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154544/can-i-call-apis-in-componentwillmount-in-react)

Comment: but if i look to my console the render is fired before axios. i have look on my console

Comment: You have added `console.log` in the response of your axios call. add one before your axios call and check

Answer (score 0):

Since the axios call is asynchronous, it might not complete and set the state with the response before the render method fires. So, you would have to check for null in your render method and render the table rows only when there is valid data available.

You can use a check like

```
{this.state.datas && this.state.datas.map . . .}
```

Also, you would need to initialize the `state` in the constructor, so that it is not `null` when accessed in the render method

```
constructore(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {datas:null};
}
```

Comment: From what I understand, `axios` uses `Promises` and that, to me, means it will run as if it were `sync`. So what do you mean it might not finish and set the state before the render is called, especially if it is called in `componentWillMount`? Perhaps `setState` is the one that is `async` and might not update the state immediately, what do you think?

Comment: @fshock As per the react docs (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) `setState` might not execute immediately to improve performance. And according to  MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) **a promise is a returned object to which you attach callbacks, instead of passing callbacks into a function.** So a promise is always `async` in its resolution.

Comment: In that MDN doc, it says *Callbacks will never be called before the completion of the current run of the JavaScript event loop.* Doesn't that mean, the sequence of the calls will be sync? If it does, then why would control be passed to the render function whereas the call chain has not finished?

Comment: @fshock The `resolve` method of the promise is the callback which would be fired to resolve the promise. Till it is fired the promise will remain unresolved. As per the code above, the call to axios will return this unresolved promise; and the state of the component will not be set. This is when the componentWillMount would complete and the first call to render will happen. Whenever the resolve callback is called, the state will be set and  this will trigger a call to shouldComponentUpdate and another call to render, which will finally render the data received from the axios call.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it is not the axios part. You have are iterating over the wrong array. 'datas' does not exist, 'data' does. Also try to find another name for the first argument of map instead of data.

```
this.state.datas.map((data, i))
```

to

```
this.state.data.map((d, i))
```

Also you need to change the part after you receive your 'data' from the server.

```
this.setState({
  datas: response.data
})
```

You dont have a 'datas' array in your state, it is called 'data'.

Also FYI. Data is plural, Datum is singular.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: case closed. problem just in the constructor

Comment: precisely, state declaration in the constructor, I use this.setState({}) rather than this.state = () and that is the problem