# ReactJS - Ajax call - Where is Legit?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

Im using reactJS 16.5.2 and Im bit confused about the next Major Release (17) where some classic method of a component LiceCycle will be deprecated (componentWillReceiveProps, componentWillUpdate and componentWillMount).

Following this post: https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-component-life-cycle-823a640b3e8d

im trying to be prepared but I can't find the correct spot to make an AjaxCall in my component to fill data of component itself.

I usually made a Wrapper Component that manage the async comunication with external server.

Component usually call that method in componentWillMount where setState is Legit.

```
componentWillMount()
{
  this.props.someAjaxCall(); //calling the Wrapped method that will call a setDate( { ajaxData : response.data } );
}

renderData()
{
   if (this.props.ajaxData === undefined) //ajax call is not ended yet
   {
      return <span> No data </span>
   }
   return <span> Lot of Data </span> //ajax call has completed
}

render()
{
   return this.renderData();
}
```

With this flow, component will be rendered two times. The first time without ajaxData filled so "No Data" will be rendered. 
At the end of the AjaxCall, the wrapper will make a setState so a new render will be called.

With this flow, I usually use shouldComponentUpdate to avoid any unnecessary rendering of any wrapped components.

The question is. With the deprecation of componentWillMount, where I have to call Ajax Async Methods?

Comment: Is there a reason not to put the call in the constructor?

Comment: `componentDidMount` is usually the lifecycle hook to fetch data from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `componentDidMount` to make AJAX calls. Even with `componentWillMount`, `componentDidMount` is the method, you should make API calls in. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154544/can-i-call-apis-in-componentwillmount-in-react)