# What is the best practice cause side effects, such as connecting to a webapi, in reactjs, and why?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning `ReactJS` currently and I've seen and read that you should use `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` but I don't Understand why should I use it when the side effect is connected to the view.

For an example, I have a submit button in a sign in page, when should I send the api the sign in data? in `componentDidMount`? or `onSubmitHandler`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the context where some one told you "you should use `componentDidMount`", but your submit button should call a function you define like "`onSubmitHandler`".

`componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` are called [lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) and you should read about them before deciding if you should use them, and what you should use them for.

Comment: Some tutorials online. So let's say I need to connect my webapi I should do it in a onClick mathod ?

Comment: Yes, if a click is the even that prompts your form to communicate to the api, then thats what you should use. Or even better, your onClick method calls a separate asynchronous function that submits to the api, and can be reused elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You should call your api in `onSubmitHandler` and call it as per your use case.

As for the the `componentDidMount`, it is generally used to call those methods which are required when a component is mounted.

You can read about lifecycle methods [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answers it completely depends upon the use cases, you can call your API in componentDidMount or in `onSubmitHandler`.

**Some common use cases:**

- When I want to call an API after my view rendered then I will use `ComponentDidMount` to simply call the API. I will not wait for any click event from user.

If someone told you "you should use componentDidMount", then they are probably talking about this use case. [Why call API in ComponentDidMount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154544/can-i-call-apis-in-componentwillmount-in-react)

- If there is a submit button on my page and I want to call API when someone clicks on that then I will use onClick event. I can't call API in ComponentDidMount in that case

There is an awesome article about the lifecycles [React 16 Lifecycle Methods: How and when to use them](https://blog.bitsrc.io/react-16-lifecycle-methods-how-and-when-to-use-them-f4ad31fb2282)