# Used Axios to call Rest Api in React JS web Application

Tags: javascript, rest, reactjs, axios

I want to know what are the best technique to achieve following things.

And I want to used Axios Library for calling Rest but got some problem in calling and consuming.

- What is the best pattern to call REST API React.
- What tools and reference to learn quicker.

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API.

Comment: does this support the full CRUD?

Comment: Yes, you can GET, POST, PUT, PATCH + DELETE. Please search for some tutorials on web. I guess you'll find plenty of help/examples there.

Comment: Hello Felix i will suggest you to study Redux and Redux-thunk then you will have better idea of handling Rest Api in react js.

Comment: https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use Ajax.

Here is an example of code that allows you to fetch data :

```
request() {
     $.ajax({
        url: "http://your/url",
        method: 'GET',
        }).then(function (data) {
            // Here process the data you fetched 
          }
     }.bind(this));
}
```

And then you can call your function somewhere in your code.
But avoid calling it within **componentWillMount**, it is highly Recommended by React docs. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139366/why-do-the-react-docs-recommend-doing-ajax-in-componentdidmount-not-componentwi).

For me, my need was to get data every n second from server, so I called it in **componentDidMount**

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.request(), 10000);
}
```

Comment: is plainajax better? or what are the advantages?