# why we prefer to write header or api request or ajax code in componentDidMount not in componentWillMount

Tags: reactjs, react-lifecycle

why we prefer to write header or api request or ajax code in componentDidMount not in componentWillMount.

need simple and clear difference with example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do the React docs recommend doing AJAX in componentDidMount, not componentWillMount?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139366/why-do-the-react-docs-recommend-doing-ajax-in-componentdidmount-not-componentwi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **`componentDidMount()`** because you need the component to be rendered in order to populate it with the data that you're fetching from the API.

```
componentWillMount(){
   //Fetch API and set the State
}

render(){
   return(<div>{this.state.myData}</div>)
}
```

When `componentWillMount()` fires up the `<div>` hasn't been rendered yet (does not exist at the moment in the DOM).

When using `componentDidMount()` in the other hand. The render method runs first creating the `<div>` element in the DOM, after that then `componentDidMount()` runs, fetching the data, you set your `state` and that creates a re-render of the component. That's why we use `componentDidMount()` to fetch data from the API. you can find more information [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).

**caveat:** **You should validate the state** so you don't get `undefined` the first time the component is render (without the data from the API).

Comment: edgaromar90 the same case with constructor also. we usually set temporary state in constructor  and constructor invokes before the initial render. both constuctor and willMount invokes before initial render, then why we are not using in componentWillMount

Comment: "componentWillMount() is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It is called before render(), therefore setting state synchronously in this method will not trigger a re-rendering. Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method." - from [React doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

Answer (score 0):

edgaromar90 the same case with constructor also. we usually set temporary state in constructor  and constructor invokes before the initial render. both constuctor and willMount invokes before initial render, then why we are not using in componentWillMount