# retrieving nested JSON objects when mapping from an api call

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, typescript, mapping

I am working on mapping JSON to Data driven rendering within react. To accomplish some of the things I need to do. I am going to require Nested JSON. 
When attempting to map this data, I keep running into values that I cannot map. Specifically when trying `(mapObject.object.value)` where I am attempting to pass the nested values into an interpolated div.

JSON

```
{"PositionComponent": [
        {
            "key": 0,
            "Elevation": {
                "positionValue": "1.11566",
                "id": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "key": 1,
            "Azimuth": {
                "positionValue": "1.145657",
                "id": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

React Components:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../HeaderBar/HeaderBar.css';
import 'whatwg-fetch';

type StatusBarProps = {};
type StatusBarState = {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
    positionStatus: any;
};

class StatusBar extends Component<StatusBarProps, StatusBarState> {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            positionStatus: []
        };
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        // maps azimuth and elevation for all objects
        fetch('http://localhost:5001/PositionComponent/').then(results => {
            return results.json();
        }).then(data => {
            let positionStatus = data.map((positioning) => {
                return (
                    <div className="temporary" key={positioning.key}>{positioning.Elevation.positionValue} : {positioning.Azimuth.positionValue}</div>
                );
            });
            this.setState({ positionStatus: positionStatus });
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="location">
                <div className="col-xs-12">
                    {this.state.positionStatus}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default StatusBar;
```

The relevant JSON has been provided for context of the issue, but is being served from JSON.server for sake of development speed. It seems that the issue is that I am receiving `Object {key: 0, Elevation: Object }  Object { key: 1, Azimuth: Object }` where I cannot go down a level into the object itself by calling `{positioning.Elevation.positionValue}`. My question is, how would I go about mapping this so that I can get those interior object values tied to Elevation, and Azimuth?

Comment: Have you tried mapping through `data.PositionComponent.map(...)` instead of `data`?

Comment: @mersocarlin I have not, but I am trying now.

Comment: @mersocarlin It throws a data.PositionComponent is undefined error

Comment: What is the output if you `console.log(data)` before mapping?

Comment: In your data, `positioning.Elevation` may or may not be defined. If you only ever have `Elevation` or `Azimuth`, then you can do:  `{(positioning.Elevation) ? positioning.Elevation.positionValue : positioning.Azimuth.positionValue}`

Comment: @RickJolly they are going to be rendered as two separate values. I will adjust my code to reflect that.

Comment: Are you using firebase as database?

Comment: @mersocarlin `Array [object, object]` is the output of data

Comment: @DamienGold I am not using a database, I am developing on a messaging system

Comment: @RickJolly Your answer worked perfectly for what i am doing here. It renders out both values. Would you mind providing this as the answer. So I can accept it?

Comment: I'd accept the answer from @Sag1v below. It is more generic and shows you not to store jsx in state.

Comment: Don't put fetch in componentWillMount. You should change it to componentDidMount. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139366/why-do-the-react-docs-recommend-doing-ajax-in-componentdidmount-not-componentwi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is that you got different keys on each object that holds the nested key you want to grab.
You may try to access it conditionally and check the existing of `Elevation` OR  `Azimuth` and access respectively.
The downside for this approach that when you add a new key, another condition should be added. So you may want a more generic approach.

You can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and `.map` through the `keys` and return the for each `positionValue`. if a certain key doesnt hold it then undefined will be evaluated which `map` will ignore and wont return it.
Something like this:

```
Object.entries(positioning).map(([key, value]) => {
  return positioning[key].positionValue;
})
```

I would take out the rendering logic out to another method and wont store a markup in state.
Another thing you will want to change is to [avoid the use of fetching or side effects in componentWillMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount)

Here is a running example of your code (i didn't use fetch as i don't have your data in a server)

```js
const dataFromServer = [
  {
    key: 0,
    Elevation: {
      positionValue: "1.11566",
      id: 0
    }
  },
  {
    key: 1,
    Azimuth: {
      positionValue: "1.145657",
      id: 1
    }
  }
];

class StatusBar extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      positionStatus: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let positionStatus = dataFromServer;
    this.setState({ positionStatus: positionStatus });
  }

  renderPositionstatus = () => {
    const { positionStatus } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {positionStatus.map(positioning => {
          return (
            <div className="temporary" key={positioning.key}>
              {Object.entries(positioning).map(([key, value]) => {
                return positioning[key].positionValue;
              })}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="location">
        <div className="col-xs-12">{this.renderPositionstatus()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<StatusBar />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Assuming I wanted to do this inside a fetch command, would I follow the same structure, and replace renderPositionStatus with the fetch?

Comment: you could technically but i advice against that. in my opinion a fetch callback responsibility is... well, to fetch the data. i would store the fetched data in the state, this will trigger another render call this time the state is not empty and the function `renderPositionstatus` for example will return the markup you want with the new data. `fetch` should only fetch data and trigger an action inside a callback in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the advisement.

Answer (score 0):

Thought it might be a JSON error, but you are trying to access an `undefined` prop within your object.

This is your `data`:

```
[
  {
    "key": 0,
    "Elevation": {
      "positionValue": "1.11566",
      "id": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "key": 1,
    "Azimuth": {
      "positionValue": "1.145657",
      "id": 1
    }
  }
]
```

Not all elements have `Elevation` nor `Azimuth` props. First one has only `Elevation` whereas second one has `Azimuth`.

Therefore, this line will always break:

```
{positioning.Elevation.positionValue} / {positioning.Azimuth.positionValue}
```

Should you need to provide at least one of them:

```
let positionStatus = data.map((positioning) => {
  return (
    <div
      className="temporary"
      key={positioning.key}
    >
      {positioning.Elevation ? positioning.Elevation.positionValue : 0} :
      {positioning.Azimuth ? positioning.Azimuth.positionValue : 0}
    </div>
  )
})
```

or

```
let positionStatus = data.map((positioning) => {
  return (
    <div
      className="temporary"
      key={positioning.key}
    >
      {positioning.Elevation
        ? positioning.Elevation.positionValue
        : positioning.Azimuth.positionValue
      }
    </div>
  )
})
```

Comment: Apologies, and to clarify that is not meant to represent a division of two numbers. It is meant to signify a division of strings where the "/" is sitting